# How to disable a text inside input box?

Tags: html, css

How can I disabled text inside a input box?

```
<input type="text" value="Username">
```

User name should be disabled. But it should be click-able inside the input box. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking to make the textbox read-only.

To make the textbox read-only, you can use [`readonly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/readonly) attribute. By making it readonly, user cannot change the value of the textbox. However, the textbox can be focused by clicking on it.

```html
<input type="text" value="Username" readonly="readonly" />
```

There's other property called `disabled`. If you use this on textbox, user cannot change the value as well as you cannot click on it.

```html
<input type="text" value="Username" disabled="disabled" />
```

**EDIT**

> only Username will be disabled. When a user click on box , Username should vanish

You can use placeholders.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
```

Comment: only Username will be disabled. When a user click on box , Username should vanish .

Comment: @Mahmudhasan You'll need javascript for that or maybe you're talking about `placeholders`

Comment: yes i'm looking for placeholder. Thank you for your answer ! :)